# Remainder of the division and approximate answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, division, approximation

have a question. Why when did write `1.262 % 1` then get `0.262`, but if `1.263 % 1` , then get `0.2629999999`? I understand then this is machine approximation, but why if I choose even numbers, then all good, but if choose odd numbers have approximation

Comment: It's *always* an approximation, just sometimes it's more proximate to your desired value and sometimes less so.